# iOS Chrome issue

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to solve a mystery:

- A page from a React web app can be loaded in Safari on iOS
- That page can be loaded in Chrome on iOS if you choose "Request Desktop Site"
- That page is blank when attempting to load it in Chrome on iOS if you go with the default "Request Mobile Site"
- The page works fine in desktop browsers

I have taken steps to enforce a timeout on the server side, in case there is a connection that is hanging.  But when I consult the logs, the requests complete quickly without any of the usual follow-on activity.  My guess is that there is a JavaScript error of some kind that is causing the React app to bail.

What is a good next step that might be helpful in troubleshooting this issue?

**ETA**: Added new information that confirms the requests are making it from Chrome to the Golang server, as expected.

I think what's going on is that the "Request Mobile Site" mode falls over when there's a large JavaScript bundle, whereas the "Request Desktop Site" doesn't for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who runs into this situation, something that worked for me was to decrease the amount of JavaScript that the iOS Chrome app has to load, e.g., using code splitting, user agent sniffing and redirection to a less memory-intensive page in the case of iOS Chrome.  After doing this, things worked fine.  I'm guessing that less memory is available to apps running in the "Request Mobile Site" mode than in the  "Request Desktop Site" mode.